# Text overflowing buttons

Tags: html, css

Our company is building an interface that allows users to drag and drop and part of this is that they can customize a buttons length in percentages.

This is actually pretty cool and I think it is very useful, however when I'm looking at the responsive aspect of it I'm running into an issue.

If the button is set to a percentage like 100% it will work fine until they scale the screen so small that the text in the button starts to overflow the background. Is there anyway to fix this without setting a fixed with on them using media queries? The text can very in length and I don't want to restrict it too much.

My html looks like this

```
<div class="form_control centered" >
    <div class="centered">
        <label class="control-label">Label</label>
    </div>

        <label class="btn btn-primary adjustableOption" > //Width can be added here
            <input  type="checkbox" />
            <span class='optionText'>Title of check</span>
        </label>
</div>
```

and my css looks like this

```
.btn .optionText{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:1em;
    text-align:left;
}

adjustableOption .optionText{
    width:90%;
}
```

And just to show what's happening here are some screenshots.

This is what it should be doing

[image: This is what it should look like.]

This is what it is doing.

[image: This is what it is doing.]

Also a jsFiddle to help. 
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8216/

Comment: In the jsfiddle I don't see anything alike the image above. But as I see it might be an inverse of height and width or a bigger padding.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue as well

Comment: Ok, I'll add bootstrap to it...

Comment: It's fine your code http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8214/

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the added width, it is not fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see in your fiddle is where you have an inline style of 50% which is cutting off the rest of your button

Comment: and that is what I need to have in there. The user can tell the interface what 'size' they want it to be. I need the content to conform to whatever width they put in there.

Answer (score -2):

`position:fixed;` will resolve this issue.
In your fiddle without bootstrap, change your btn-primary class into this:

```
.btn, .btn-primary{
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;

}
```

**Another option:**

In Bootstrap, the .btn class has a white-space: nowrap; property, making it so that the button text won't wrap. So, after setting that to normal, the text should wrap to the next line if the text would exceed the set width.

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: I cannot add a position of fixed to all my buttons...that will stop the responsiveness.

Comment: I have already added the white-space further up in my code, sorry for not adding that in my question. It's still overhanging the button.

Comment: If you add whitespace:normal to the class of btn (.btn) your fiddle goes well :)

Comment: But, that puts the checkbox above my text, I I need it to sit beside it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: and I just did a quick test in my dev environment and the text is still coming out of the button